# Dividing columns by group (Grouping in data frame)

Tags: r

I would like to calculate relative response values by dividing each response/column by its' group mean.
I have managed to produce an exhaustive (and thus unsatisfying) method. My data set is very large and contains multiple groups and responses.

```
###############
# example

# used packages
require(plyr)

# sample data
group <- c(rep("alpha", 3), rep("beta", 3), rep("gamma", 3))
a <- rnorm(9, 10,1) #some random data as response
b <- rnorm(9, 10,1) 
df <- data.frame(group, a, b)

# my approach
# means for each group and response
df.means <- ddply(df, "group", colwise(mean))

# clunky method
df$rel.a[df$group=="alpha"] <- 
    df$a[df$group=="alpha"]/df.means$a[df.means$group=="alpha"]
df$rel.a[df$group=="beta"] <- 
    df$a[df$group=="beta"]/df.means$a[df.means$group=="beta"]
# ... etc
df$rel.b[df$group=="gamma"] <- 
    df$b[df$group=="gamma"]/df.means$b[df.means$group=="gamma"]

#desired outcome (well, perhaps with no missing values)
df
###############
```

I have been using r for a while now, but I still struggle with trivial data handling procedures. I believe I must be missing something, How can I better address these group(s)?

Comment: As my post was ambigously stated:  @David's method adds columns by using data.table (solution based on my code)  docendo's method converts the whole data frame by using dplyr (solution based on my question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easily understandable with the package dplyr, the next version of plyr for data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate_each(funs(./mean(.)))
```

The . represents the data in each column (by group). mutate_each is used to modify each column except the grouping variables. You specify inside the funs argument which functions should be applied to each column.

Comment: Even cleaner than mine!

Comment: Very sleek! Thank you very much, this deals with my actual data set -as is.

Comment: You're welcome. You may be interested in having a look at the [introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) or RStudio's [data wrangling cheatsheet](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table` package you can do this whole thing fast and easy in one line (without creating the `df.means` at all), simply

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste0("real.", names(df)[-1]) := 
            lapply(.SD, function(x) x/mean(x)), 
          group]
```

This will run over all the column within `df` (except `group`) by `group` and divide each value by the group mean

---

**Edit:** If you want to override the original columns (like in the `dplyr` answer, you can do this with small modification (remove the `paste0` part):

```
setDT(df)[, names(df)[-1] := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/mean(x)), group]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I accepted docendo's answer because I personally like the dplyr syntax better. data.table seems powerful but a bit daunting, conversely, dplyr will hopefully enter my active coding vocabulary.

Comment: @EfEx From your original code, it seems like you want to create new columns along with the original columns.  In that case either DavidArenburg's or Avraham's answer is more correct.

Comment: @akrun You are correct, the code suggests that. However, the code is based on my limited data handling skills (and the respected commenting line "desired outcome" obviously on my limited presenting skills). I am sorry for the confusion. I would have upvoted David's solution, as soon as I got it because it generically solves the code problem, but unfortunately I am not (yet) allowed to do that.

Comment: @akrun yes, thank you, and thank you for pointing that out. I am not sure whether post-hoc changing the question/code would increase confusion, therefore, I added a comment.

Comment: See my edit, you can reach the exact output of `dplyr` solution too with it.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you can also do this easily in `dplyr`. Given the above data

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(aresp = a/ mean(a), bresp= b/mean(b))
```

returns:

```
  group         a         b     aresp     bresp
1 alpha 10.052847  8.076405 1.0132828 0.8288214
2 alpha 10.002243 11.447665 1.0081822 1.1747888
3 alpha  9.708111  9.709265 0.9785350 0.9963898
4  beta 10.732693  7.483065 0.9751125 0.8202278
5  beta 11.719656 11.270522 1.0647824 1.2353754
6  beta 10.567513  8.615878 0.9601051 0.9443968
7 gamma 10.221040 11.181763 1.0035630 0.9723315
8 gamma 10.302611 11.286443 1.0115721 0.9814341
9 gamma 10.030605 12.031643 0.9848649 1.0462344
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I accepted @docendo's answer as it deals (generically) with multiple columns.

Comment: @EfEx, no arguments, his is the better answer (which is why I upvoted it as well :) ).